# SQL Server Query takes over 50 seconds to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query that I'm trying to run. Right now, I am using a start and end date parameter. After about 50 seconds, I get a total of 33 rows, which I feel is an extraordinary amount of time. When I remove the parameters, 1582 rows are returned; this only takes 53 seconds to return.

I am at a total loss of what to do. I have tried taking out any redundant joins (there were a few); this did nothing to reduce the query return time. If it's possible, being able to return the query under 30 seconds would be great. Thank you.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2017-07-31 08:00:00.000'
SELECT
 a.PrimaryEventID, 
 b.Event_Name as 'PrimaryEventName',
 b.Event_StartTime as 'EventDate',
 e.UserLastName+', '+e.UserFirstName as 'Operator',
 f.Activity_MetaDataFieldValue as 'Type',
 'Status' = Case
        When c.EventStatus = 0 then 'Tent' 
        When c.EventStatus = 1 then 'Appr' 
        When c.EventStatus = 2 then 'Pend' 
        Else 'No Status Found' 
 End,
 CONVERT(varchar(20), a.PrimaryEventID)+'|'+CONVERT(varchar(20), e.UserId) 
 as 'JoinColumn',
 b1.Activity_MetaDataTypeID
FROM
  views.mcd_DWH_LinkedEvents a
  Left JOIN dwh.mcd_DWH_Events b ON a.PrimaryEventID = b.Event_ID
  Left JOIN rawViews.mcd_DWH_ActivitiesBasicData b1 on b.EventActivity_ID = b1.Activity_ID
  Left JOIN dwh.mcd_DWH_Events c ON a.LinkedEventID = c.Event_ID
  Left JOIN dwh.mcd_FWT_UserEventAssociations_Detailed_Manager d ON a.LinkedEventID = d.Event_ID 
  Left JOIN views.mcd_FWT_UsersBasicData e ON d.User_ID = e.UserID
  Left JOIN views.mcd_FWT_ActivitiesExtraDetails f ON c.EventActivity_ID = f.Activity_ID and f.Activity_MetaDataFieldName = 'Type'
  Left JOIN views.mcd_FWT_TrainingProgramsBasicData g ON c.EventTrainingProgram_ID = g.TrainingProgramID
  Left JOIN views.mcd_FWT_MPlansBasicData h ON g.TrainingProgram_MPlanID = h.MPlanID
WHERE d.Activity_TypeID = 57 
  and b.Event_StartTime between @StartDate and @EndDate
  and (f.Activity_MetaDataFieldValue = 'Qual' or f.Activity_MetaDataFieldValue = 'Run' or f.Activity_MetaDataFieldValue = 'Assess' ) 
GROUP by a.PrimaryEventID, b.Event_Name,b.Event_StartTime, h.MPlanName, f.Activity_MetaDataFieldValue, e.UserLastName, e.UserFirstName, c.EventStatus, e.UserId, b1.Activity_MetaDataTypeID
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns you're joining? And is `b.Event_StartTime` a DATETIME field as well (ie: is it the same datatype as the variables you're using to query it? If not, the index won't be used)

Comment: When you look at the query plan does it suggest any indexes?  If I had to guess, those views you have probably all take a couple of seconds each and it adds up.

Comment: There's nothing we can do here without seeing, at the very least, the execution plan.

Comment: When you say you remove the parameters, are you actually just omitting the line in the where with the 'BETWEEN'? If so, I would say your database is having some issues doing the comparisons on the dates, and as the others have suggested, it could be index related. First place to look is the execution plan.

Comment: Not an answer to the question at hand but something you should consider as this is a lot harder to read than it needs to be. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: I think you have some underlying issues here. You said when you remove the parameters it takes 53 seconds to return 1,582 rows. That is about 52 seconds longer than it should take. You seem to rely very heavily on views. Do those views by chance select data from other views?

Comment: @SteveB Sorry, I'm still a newbie with SQL. I tried to do an execution plan, but received "SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'Main'."

Comment: @RobbieToyota I have indexes on the columns I'm joining. b.Event_StartTime is a DATETIME field.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you. The example on there is definitely easier to read.  I will make sure to try and put better formatting into practice from now on. The views does not select data from other views.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's knock out expectation vs reality.  It sounds as though you logically assume that a Where statement would make your query take less time. And while logically, that seems to make sense, this is not how SQL Server operates.

Consider https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/from there we see an order of operation of

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
   10 ORDER BY
10. TOP

SQL Server actually completes the full query **then** limits it by your WHERE parameters.  If you have administrative access to the tables in this database, I would consider adding indexing on, at minimum:

- dwh.mcd_DWH_Events on field Event_StartTime
- EventID, LinkedEventID, and UserID in every table (if not primary keys)
- dwh.mcd_FWT_UserEventAssociations_Detailed_Manager on field Activity_TypeID
- views.mcd_FWT_ActivitiesExtraDetails on field Activity_MetaDataFieldValue

A good rule of thumb is dates and ids should be indexed, and generally, any field which you are reasonably going to place into a where statement on a regular basis.

Comment: All good points but they potentially don't really answer the problem that OP has, mainly because nobody can answer it as we don't have enough information...

Comment: This is the **logical** order of operation. Not physical. "SQL Server actually completes the full query then limits it by your WHERE parameters" is definitely not a statement you can consider to be generally true. This is the point of a query optimizer.